# Jquery mmenu and WCAG

Tags: jquery, mmenu

I am trying to make my site WCAG compatible because lately it is obligatory for European Union programs. That means to make sure it easy for people with disabilities to surf at my site.

The only issue I have is with jQuery mmenu v6.1.0
There is a a tag that contains no text, check the error the validator gives me:
https://wave.webaim.org/report#/https://battery-eshop.gr/

The specific code is:

```
<a class="mm-title" href="#undefined" aria-hidden="true"></a>
```

I am using WordPress and the code is coming from Theme-Folder/js/mmenu/jquery.mmenu.js I guess.
Any help fixing it? I cant find the code in this or alter this some how.

Thank you